# Is it supposed to be a HTML or an HTML

Tags: word-choice, indefinite-articles

I've seen many people who say:

> This is ***a*** HTML page.

Yet I've also seen many people who say:

> This is ***an*** HTML page.

Are both usages equally correct?

Or, which is the *grammatically* correct one?

---

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“A” vs. “An” in writing vs. pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/a-vs-an-in-writing-vs-pronunciation)
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Comment: related to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic

Comment: also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms

Comment: We have a [blog article](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) that explains this and much more!

Comment: if you want to get very technical, it's an HTML document

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It depends on whether you say [aitch or haitch](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/how-does-one-correctly-pronounce-the-letter-h-aych-or-haych).

- An aitch tee em el page
- A haitch tee em el page

Comment: You can hear both of them here: http://www.forvo.com/word/html/

Comment: ...what do you put down when you're writing, then?

Comment: @Standback I say *aitch* so I write "an HTML page"

Comment: **HUT-MUL** made my day ))) English lacks letters to describe the sounds that are used to pronounce it the way it's done at my origin, something like **ha t m[u-e] l[u-e]** which is fun to compare

Comment: This answer is not very helpful to me, because I don't know whether people reading my texts will say "aitch" or "haitch". I just want to know the most correct/common form, so I stick to it when writing (either "an H" or "a H").

Comment: Both are regarded as standard, though it seems that (apart from Catholic-educated Ireland and its derivatives) *aitch* and *an HTML page* are probably more common across the English speaking world

Answer (score 13):

The choice between *a* and *an* is determined by the initial sound, and not the initial letter, of the following word. Most people pronounce 'h' as 'aitch', making *an* appropriate. (I say 'most', because some people pronounce it as 'haitch'.)

Answer (score 5):

An html (echh-tee-em-el) but a hyper text...
Similarly, an MBA but a Masters of Business....

Answer (score 3):

When you read it aloud, it's "Aitch Tee Em El". The first sound is a vowel. So it should be "an HTML".

Answer (score 2):

"An HTML snippet" is correct. The reason we have two versions of the indefinite article ("a" and "an") is to help with pronunciation - what the French call liaison. "An" is used when the following noun begins with a vowel *sound*, so it would be perverse to use "a" simply because the next letter is a consonant. For the same reason "an hotel" used to be correct, as it was customary to drop the H.

Comment: Note that this means different pronunciation dialects may make different -- but equally correct -- choices about a/an.

Answer (score -4):

"H" stands for "hyper..." ; the "h" of all the words starting by hyper is never aspirated (*an* hyperbol, etc.).

Then : **an** HTML.

Comment: Please review [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155/3559) to understand why your answer misses the point. Pronunciation of HTML has nothing to do with the pronunciation of *hyper-*.

Comment: @Matt Эллен. Please could you explain my mistake ? The "H" refers to "Hypertext", whereas it has nothing to do with the pronunciation of HTML ?

Comment: Your answer seems to state: the H of HTML mean hyper, so the article used in front of HTML should be *an*. This reasoning is flawed as the expansion of an initialism (that is pronounced as the initialism, such as HTML) does not affect what article is used.