# Which indefinite article are we supposed to use before a known abbreviated noun starting with "H"?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, indefinite-articles

I'm asking this because I couldn't find any answer on whether I should use "a" or "an" before an abbreviated word starting with "H" like "H.B.H", People seem to use "a" in these cases (been reading some articles and witnessed this), but it doesn't sound correct phonetics wise.

*I searched the site but the questions seem to be concerned with non-abbreviated cases.*

Hopefully, an SE member will have a logical input to this.

Comment: Related [When should I use "a" versus "an" in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h) and [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms / initialisms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms)

Comment: also [Is it supposed to be a HTML or an HTML](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/is-it-supposed-to-be-a-html-or-an-html)

Comment: The question can be reopened if you edit, and explain why none of the linked questions are useful, but I think you will find them helpful.

Comment: You'll find a very well-written answer here: ["A" vs. "An" in writing vs. pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/)

Comment: The second link also somewhat explains the silent h case. See also a third one for a "nonstressed h" case like "an historic ...": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h