# “a href ” or “an href ”

Tags: indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it supposed to be a HTML or an HTML](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/is-it-supposed-to-be-a-html-or-an-html)
>   [When should I use “a” versus “an” in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)
>   [How does one correctly pronounce the letter 'H': “Aych” or “haych”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/how-does-one-correctly-pronounce-the-letter-h-aych-or-haych)

While not strictly a programming question, it does appear when talking about programming and in documentation, etc.

It is proper to say *a href* or *an href*? (This anchor has (a/an) href element.)

I am familiar with the English rule of using an iff the next word starts with a vowel, but many blogs are saying *an href*. I was wondering if *href* is an exception or those blogs have incorrect usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*An href* would be correct, because it's correctly pronounced as *aitch-ref*. Since this gives it the sound of a leading vowel, you use *an*.

Comment: I agree - Even though it starts with a consonant, it is a vowel sound.  Saying "a href" is awkward (try it). I can't do it without saying "an".

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to say it is *an href*.

The usage of *a/an* is dictated by the **sound** of the word following the article.  Generally, if the word is pronounced with a vowel sound at the beginning, then you use *an*.  If the word following is pronounced with a non-vowel sound, then you use *a*.

For abbreviations, the same rule applies: you just use the pronunciation of the abbreviated form.  In this case *href* is pronounced *ayh-ref*, the *ay* part being a vowel sound; hence the use of *an*.

If you say *hyperlink*, then the first sound of the word is *h*, which is not a vowel sound; hence the *a*.

[Source](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you pronounce *href* — which is basically a matter of how you pronounce *H*.  If you start it with a vowel sound, like *aitch*, then it is *an*; if you start it with a consonant like *haitch*, then it should be *a*.  *Aitch* is the most normal. but *haitch* is common in some accents.