# What is the current state of the pronunciation of the name of the letter H in England?

Tags: pronunciation, hypercorrection

The standard pronunciation of the name of the letter H is something like “aitch”. There is a variant pronunciation as “haitch”, which I have mostly seen described as originally a result of hyper-correction (because [one shouldn’t drop one’s haitches](http://idiotic-hat.blogspot.com/2017/11/leave-it-out.html)). Just from watching Youtube videos (in the things that I watch this may come up for example in terms like HDMI or HDR), it seems to me that the form starting with an h-sound is actually prevalent among young speakers from England (and maybe Ireland, Wales, Scotland). As to the meaning of “young” in that statement, the instance that prompted me to finally write this question was a thirty year old astrophysicist.

Now I am sure that my own observation is prone to all kinds of biases. Is there any actual data or some kind of general consensus on the state of the pronunciation of the name of the letter H among young speakers in England? I am actually interested in all of British English, but if it helps to concentrate on England or some regions thereof, then that is fine. I have heard that the phenomenon also exists in Australia, but it is probably better to keep this question focussed on British English.

Remark: I am aware that this topic [has come up here before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/how-does-one-correctly-pronounce-the-letter-h-aych-or-haych), but questions often asked for the correct pronunciation, which mine does not. Also, I think that the phenomenon is sufficiently recent so that a 10 year old answer may not describe the current state.

Comment: If you want to fund a sociolinguistic study, you could actually find out definitively. Failing that, make up your own story and claim it's true. That's what everybody else does.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I see your point. However, as you will have guessed, I am neither a linguist nor a native speaker of English. I also do not live in England. So I think that others will have a better overview of and access to the existing literature. And absent that, maybe that is something that linguists in England discuss over tea, what do I know ;)

Comment: Haitch or aitch? How a humble letter was held hostage by historical haughtiness. https://www.independent.co.uk/news/long_reads/haitch-or-aitch-pronunciation-letter-h-old-english-a8393766.html - 
Why H is the most contentious letter in the alphabet. https://www.theguardian.com/science/shortcuts/2013/nov/04/letter-h-contentious-alphabet-history-alphabetical-rosen - 'Haitch' or 'aitch'? How do you pronounce 'H'? https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-11642588

Comment: There are all kinds of difficulties with the pronunciations of /h/ in English. And those just underlie the impossibility of getting accurate data on any pronunciations. Especially if they're topics of social differentiation ("(h)aitch-dropping" is a mark of low status in UK English).

Comment: Aspirated ***haitch*** is just a whimsical / facetious usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What rhymes with H? :)

Comment: @tchrist: Over the years I've seen countless instances of people asking *What rhymes with **orange, purple, wolf, month, music, rainbow...*** (those are just the first half-dozen Google "autocomplete" suggestions to follow the first three italicised words there). But I don't remember anyone asing what rhymes with ***H*** before. Presumably it's just not the kind of word/letter that easily arises at the end of a line of verse! :)

Comment: I understand that I may be asking for data that just does not exist, even though it could. I wonder whether that was that sufficient reason for a downvote.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that even in today's "global village", there are **a lot** of different accents across England, and even more once you include Wales, Scotland, and Ireland. This particular feature also has strong associations with class and social status, and has had for several generations. So rather than a clear recent growth, or generational difference, I would expect any study you do find to show a shifting pattern of regional and social variation.

Comment: @JohnLawler The insertion of (h)extraneous /h/ sounds is (h)also a mark of low status but usually indicates an unsuccessful attempt to raise one's status.

Comment: I'm sure there's a vast sociolinguistic literature about initial /h/ in English lects.